# xUnit, SpecFlow Selenium and ITestOutputHelper problem

Tags: c#, selenium, xunit, specflow

Still having a problem with a automation test project in VS Code using C#, Selenium, SpecFlow and xUnit
I am trying to output to logs with ITestOutputHelper as the test progress.

So I have this class

```
using Xunit.Abstractions;

[Binding]
public class Logging
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _testOutputHelper;

    public Logging(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper)
    {
        _testOutputHelper = testOutputHelper;
    }

    public void WriteOutput(string theMessage)
    {
        _testOutputHelper.WriteLine(theMessage);
    }
}
```

Which is called from this class

```
public static class WriteLog
{
    static string _logout;

    public static void WriteLogData(string logout)
    {
        _logout = logout;
    }

    public static void WriteToLog(this Logging logger)
    {
        logger.WriteOutput(_logout);
    }
}
```

And I am trying to call WriteLog from the tests with the following

```
public static void WriteToReport(string theMessage)
{
    WriteLog. WriteLogData(theMessage);
    WriteLog. WriteToLog();
}
```

But I get an error with `WriteLog.WriteToLog();`
The error is

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'logger' of 'WriteLog.WriteToLog(Logging)'
```

So my question is, how do I send log information to Logging.WriteOutput?

Can anyone offer any advice please?

Thanks in advance

Kev

Comment: I think you have here a problem with your method names. The WriteToLog extension method for the Logging class and the other WriteToLog(string) method are in each way. Try to rename one of them so something else.

Comment: @AndreasWillich noted, these had already been changed and problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution

```
Step Class TestAppSteps
```

using Xunit.Abstractions;

```
[Binding]
public sealed class TestAppSteps : TestAppPage
{
    public TestAppSteps(ITestOutputHelper output) : base(output)
    {
    }

    code
}
```

Page Class TestAppPage
using Xunit.Abstractions;

```
public class TestAppPage : PageAssertions
{

    public TestAppPage(ITestOutputHelper output) : base(output)
    {

    }
    
    code
}
```

Utility Class PageAssertions
using Xunit.Abstractions;

```
public class PageAssertions : SharedClass
{
    public PageAssertions(ITestOutputHelper output) : base(output) { }

    code inc'
    WriteToReport("Pass: URL is correct");
}
```

Utility Class SharedClass
using Xunit.Abstractions;

```
public abstract class SharedClass : OutputFunctions
{
    public SharedClass(ITestOutputHelper output) 
        : base(output)
    {
    }
    
    shared code including
    WriteToReport(GetTheCurrentMethod());
}
```

Abstract Class OutputFunctions

using Xunit.Abstractions;

```
public abstract class OutputFunctions
{
    protected readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;

    public OutputFunctions(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        _output = output;
    }

    public void WriteToReport(string theMessage)
    {
        _output.WriteLine(theMessage);
    }
}
```